# Updating color fill effects and widths in a ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have previously asked a question on plotting a barplot with standard errors in R. [Creating barplot with standard errors plotted in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468497/creating-barplot-with-standard-errors-plotted-in-r). The answer worked perfectly for what I needed. However, I would like to ask if it is possible to modify the graphics of the plot.

Firstly, how do I modify the widths of each factor on the x-axis so that each bar is equal? So in the example below, site B will be wider so the widths of each bar for "before", "during" and "after" are equal.

Secondly, in reality I have more factors than these three, but the plot (irritatingly) should not have colour. I can't find anything on fill effects for plotting a pattern on each bar. So possibly a white background with black diagonal line for some, such as in [this](http://cw.routledge.com/textbooks/matlab/Solutions_Chapter_10_04.png) picture. Is this possible in ggplot? If so, grey and black fills for "before" and "after", with some kind of pattern for "during" would be ideal.

Apologies for the specificity, but I can't find a way to alter the widths consistently for each site and update fill effects.

Here's an example dataset:

```
site <- c(rep("a", 8),
      rep("b", 11),
      rep("c", 8))
values <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 3*9, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
when <- as.factor(c(rep(c("Before","After"),each = 4),
   rep("During", 3),
   rep("Before", 4),
   rep("After", 4),
   rep(c("Before","After"),each = 4)))
df <- data.frame(when,site,values)
```

Here is the output I have arrived at thus far:

```
library(plotrix) 
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2) 
grouped_df<-group_by(df,when,site)
summarised_df<-summarise_each(grouped_df,funs(mean=mean,std_error=std.error))
limits <- aes(ymax = mean + std_error, ymin=mean-std_error)
g<-ggplot(summarised_df,aes(site,mean,fill=when))
g<-g+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = position_dodge())
g<-g+geom_errorbar(limits,width=0.25,position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
g
```

Thank you in advance for any help on modifying these graphics.

Comment: The column names were updated, it was working on mine but I have changed the variable name to "when" to avoid confusion. Apologies, I am mixing code from a previous example but updating it for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to fix the bar widths. This is happening as you don't have any data for some of the factor combinations, and ggplot dumps them.

I think the easiest way is to use `complete` from `tidyr` so that we have all combinations of factors:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% complete(when, site, fill = list(0))
```

This will make all non existing factor combinations as 0.

To fix the colours we can force ggplot to use grey-scale using `scale_fill_grey()`.

[image]
Here's the complete code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(plotrix) 
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2) 
grouped_df <- df %>% complete(when, site, fill = list(0)) %>% 
                     group_by(when, site) %>%
                     summarise_each(funs(mean = mean, std_error = std.error))
limits <- aes(ymax = mean + std_error, ymin = mean - std_error)
g <- ggplot(summarised_df, aes(site, mean, fill = when)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
            geom_errorbar(limits, width = 0.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
            scale_fill_grey()
g
```

Comment: This is fantastic thank you! The scale_fill_grey looks great. 
Is there a way following this to align the bar in the centre for each factor? So for a and c, position the black/grey border directly above each respective letter?

Comment: It's a little more fiddling, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28904303/3760920) for an example.